# Would there be forces acting on a body as it traverses space near a wormhole?

Tags: wormholes

If I think of the 2D explanation of a wormhole - how it's a topology that lets the ant crawl to a different place on the folded paper - there is no hint that the ant will experience any forces on it as it traverses this part of its (bent in 3D) 2D space-time.

Is there any reason that an object traversing the area near a wormhole in our 3D space time would feel anything unusual in terms of forces acting on it?   Where would these forces be "coming from"?

Popular science fiction depicts the journey through a wormhole as something very eventful.

I'm wondering why the 3D space in this area is any different to the space we traverse elsewhere?    Does going near "bent" space result in forces on us?

Comment: I guess it would experience forces from stars and other celestial objects on the other side of the wormhole...

Comment: Right - I was more meaning "forces as a result of the wormhole itself" ... as a result of this "bent" space-time.

Comment: Even then, since a wormhole is a warp in space-time, there should be powerful gravitational forces.

Comment: That's what I don't understand.   Why should there be?   Note that in order for the wormhole to be set up, the _whole_ of space-time has to be bent in 4D, to get the destination near to the source in 4D.   Does this mean that if a wormhole exists, the whole of our space-time will experience gravitational forces due to that bending?   Does this in fact prove that there are no wormholes, since there aren't such forces?   (Thinks: is dark energy a manifestation of bent spacetime?!)

Comment: The term you're looking for is tidal effect or tidal forces.  The answer is probably extreme tidal forces for human-sized objects but we'll see what the answers say.

Comment: I think of wormholes as two black holes connected to each other. I hope that helps...

Comment: @BrandonEnright ... actually, tidal forces are only one type of force that might exist.   The other commenter thinks of wormholes as black holes: that would imply that the wormhole inflicts gravitation on the body.   I don't understand why this would be the cases: there is no matter in a wormhole (is there?)

Answer (score 3):

First let's be perfectly clear on one point: There is no evidence whatsoever that wormholes exist in nature; in fact all evidence points toward their existence as being impossible. Wormholes require the existence of a new class of matter that we have no reason to believe exists. Furthermore, the existence of a wormhole would undermine causality in the universe as we know it.

Now, supposing you found some magical material that lets you create a wormhole. The *topology* (loosely, the global connectivity) of spacetime would be nontrivial, but the *geometry* (the local sense of size and direction) would not be so exotic. Indeed, general relativity is predicated on the geometrical notion that spacetime is a *smooth manifold*. In other words, it locally looks like the flat spacetime of special relativity. In still other words, around any point we can always find a small enough region and a suitable change of coordinates such that physics looks arbitrarily close to special relativity in the region, with no gravity to speak of.

As long as your wormhole warped spacetime gently enough, regions the size of a person or a starship or whatever can be taken to be small enough in the above sense. That is, the internal tidal forces stretching or shearing you as you traverse the wormhole can be made arbitrarily small with enough tinkering with the wormhole's parameters. This is the [equivalence principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle) at work -- inside a small enough free-falling box, you cannot even in principle tell what gravitational fields might be around you, warping spacetime.

Comment: Thanks!  I appreciate that there's no evidence that they exist, and that changing the topology of the universe to create them appears to be impossible.   I'm mostly interested in understand the implications of the "theory", as much as a lay person can.   Your description matches my impression: that a gently enough wormhole would not exert tidal forces (too badly).   What about "sucking inwards" forces?   One commenter said he thinks of a wormhole as a black hole at each end.  That would imply gravitation inwards.  But I can't see why this would be the case...

Comment: Well if there's a typical black hole at both ends you'll have a hard time getting out, won't you? In any event, I can imagine, at least mathematically, a geometrically flat spacetime (no gravity at all) that is topologically multiply connected (essentially, having wormholes).